# C++, Enum and OR condition

Tags: c++, enums

I have an enum with 3 values:

```
enum InputState { Pressed, Released, Held };
```

And I'm using it in this code:

```
//GetState returns an InputState
if(myInput.GetState(keyCode) == InputState::Pressed)
{
    //This means "keyCode" has the state "Pressed"
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

```
if(myInput.GetState(keyCode) == (InputState::Pressed || InputState::Held))
{
    //This is always false
}
if((myInput.GetState(keyCode) == InputState::Pressed) || (myInput.GetState(keyCode) == InputState::Held))
{
    //This works as intended, triggers when "keyCode" is either Pressed OR Held
}
```

As a test, I did:

```
//Using the same values from the enum, but as int now
if(1 == (1 || 2))
{
    //This works as intended
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

|| is a binary operation that expects two boolean values. In your example, the boolean values are the result of testing for equality with ==.

To see why your simplified example works, let's evaluate the expression

```
1 == (1 || 2)
```

We must start inside the parentheses first, so we are going to first evaluate `(1 || 2)`. In C++, any non-zero value is equivalent to `true` when it is used in a boolean expression, so `(1 || 2)` is equivalent to `(true || true)` which evaluates to `true`. So now our expression is

```
1 == true
```

Again, `1` is equivalent to `true` in this context, so this comparison is the same as `true == true`, which of course evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are missing something.  This worked by total accident:

```
(1 == (1 || 2))
```

It is NOT set comparison.  It simply calculated `(1 || 2)` as `true`, then converted `true` to its integral value (`1`).

The same thing would have happened with

```
(1 == (1 || 4))
(1 == (0 || 1))
(1 == (0 || 4))
```

and they all are true.

But

```
(2 == (1 || 2))
```

is false.